# How to make my hint button only turn the unmatched cards

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I've made a memory card matching game for kids for my class in college. I have a hint button that turns all the cards for a second and then turns them back over. It works fine except: when I match a card the opacity goes to 0.25, but when I press the hint button the opacity goes to 1 and then it shows the card back at 0.25 opacity instead of the card face at 0.25. Which isn't a huge issue, except the user could match that pair again and get more points. I know my tutor will probably catch this small issue.

How do I make only the unmatched cards turn?

My card div HTML:

```
<div class="container-top">
      <div class="card unmatched"></div>
      <div class="card unmatched"></div>
      <div class="card unmatched"></div>
      <div class="card unmatched"></div>
      <div class="card unmatched"></div>
      <div class="card unmatched"></div>
    </div>
```

My hint function:

```
//Function to turn cards when hint button clicked
function showHint() {
  {
    //show card hint side
    $(".card").each(function () {
      $(this)
        .html("<img src='" + $(this).data("cardValue") + "'/>")
        .show();
    });
  }
  setTimeout(function () {
    //show card back side
    $(".card").html("<img src= 'Elements/images/CardBack.jpg' />").show();
  }, 1000);
  score = score - hintclick;
  $(".scorecounter").html("Score: " + score);
}
```

Not sure what other code you need, so I'll add in the rest of the game play functions:

```
//Function to check if user selection match
function checkMatch() {
  //runs function if 2 cards are selected
  if ($(".selected").length === 2) {
    //Checks if both card match
    if ($(".selected").first().data("cardValue") === $(".selected").last().data("cardValue")) {
      //plays sound if pairs are matched
      $("#matchedpair")[0].play();
      //removes card if matched and removes 'unmatched' tag
      $(".selected").each(function () {
        $(this).animate({ opacity: 0.25 }).removeClass("unmatched");
      });

      //adds to score if match
      score = score + correctMatch;
      $(".scorecounter").html("Score: " + score);

      //removes 'selected' tag after checked
      $(".selected").each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("selected");
      });
      checkMatches();
    } else {
      //plays sound if pairs don't match
      $("#mismatchedpair")[0].play();
      //flips card back over after 1 second if not a match
      setTimeout(function () {
        //removes 'selected' tag after checked
        $(".selected").each(function () {
          $(this).html("").removeClass("selected");
        });
      }, 500);
      score = score - wrongMatch;
      $(".scorecounter").html("Score: " + score);
    }
  }
} // End of checkMatch function

//Moves to next level once all matches are made
function checkMatches() {
  if ($(".unmatched").length === 0) {
    $("#levelcomplete")[0].play();
    $(".level3complete").show();
  }
} //End of checkMatches func
```

I originally thought adding an 'if' statement around my hint function would've helped, but either I've done it wrong or it's just not the correct answer.

Comment: as far as i understand you can just use `$(".card.unmatched")` to select only the cards with class unmatched

Comment: So simple and fixed the issue. Thank you! I didn't know I could do the .card.unmatched

Comment: I´m glad it works for you :) If you dont mind pls. accept my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as i understand you want to use

`$(".card.unmatched")`

to select only cards with class unmatched

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors